# On the difference between "for(a, b&&c, d) {...}" and "for(a, b, d) if(c) {...}"

Tags: c, for-loop

As a programmer of long standing, it's sobering to realise that even the humble `for` loop is not fully comprehended. Why does the following program print a single `1` to the console? I fully expect the first loop to also produce a `1`! Compiled with `-ansi` switch.

```
/* gcc installed version: 4:4.4.4-1ubuntu2 */

#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 2

int main()
{
  int i;  
  int a[SIZE];

  a[0]=0; 
  a[1]=1;

  for(i=0; (i<SIZE) && (a[i]!=0); i++)        
    printf("%i\n",a[i]); 

  for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)   
    if (a[i]!=0)  
      printf("%i\n",a[i]);      

  return 0;      
}
```

Comment: The first loop terminates "early".

Comment: <bangs head on wall> Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the difference between this:

```
for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)   
  if (a[i]!=0)  
    printf("%i\n",a[i]);
  else
    continue; // implicit in your version with the if statement
```

and this:

```
for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)   
  if (a[i]!=0)  
    printf("%i\n",a[i]);
  else
    break; // equivalent of what the non if statement version does.
```

(Credit goes to @ta.speot.is for actually spotting the problem, this is merely an explanation)

Answer (score 1):

the first loop is equivalent to:

```
for(i=0; ; i++) {
    if( !((i<SIZE) && (a[i]!=0)))
        break;      
    printf("%i\n",a[i]); 
}
```